# Can we approximate a smooth function by a continuous and nowhere smooth function uniformly?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, approximation-theory

From Stone-Weierstrass approximation theorem we know that we can approximate a continuous(no matter differentiable or not) by a polynomial function uniformly within a compact interval domain.
                                 But,can we approximate a smooth function by a nowhere smooth continuous function uniformly?

Comment: The question in the title is different from the question in the question body

Comment: thanks for noticing,I have changed it.

Comment: Can you construct a continuous bounded nowhere smooth function ?

Comment: Nowhere differentiable functions are dense in the space of continuous functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Let $g:[-1,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a given smooth function. Let  $g_n:[-1,1]\to\mathbb{R}$
be a sequence of polynomial that converges uniformly to $g$ and let $h:[-1,1]\to\mathbb{R}$
be a bounded nowhere differentiable function. Then the sequence $$v_n (t)=g_n (t) +n^{-1} h(t) $$ is a sequence of nowhere differentiable functions that converges to $g$ uniformly.